# Why doesn't an AC solenoid valve open and close as the AC current alternates?

Tags: ac, solenoid

I'm asking about a true AC solenoid here, not a rectified AC solenoid.

Why doesn't an AC solenoid valve open and close with the AC current?

I've found descriptions of shading rings, but it appears that they only solve zero crossing problems.

If one direction of current opens the valve, why doesn't the opposite direction close it?

The question answered previously, "Why doesn't an AC solenoid coil change magnetic polarity on each cycle?", does not answer my question. The focus of that question is simply the polarity change of the solenoid. The focus of my question is the force of the changing polarity on the core.

Answer (score 2):

> *If one direction of current opens the valve, why doesn't the opposite
> direction close it?*

A piece of iron (a nail for instance) is equally attracted to north as well as south and the same is true of an AC electromagnet. It will attract an unmagnetized iron piece in both polarities equally.

The [shading coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading_coil) keeps the armature from chattering.

Comment: If the piece of iron were replaced with a magnet, then it *would* chatter and behave as the OP imagines.  But iron doesn't itself become permanently magnetic (much, see [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis)).  To permanently magnetize iron, either a) pulse with a *very strong* magnetic field, or b) heat above the [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) and let cool while in a strong magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

The reluctance force is attractive only, because it is proportional to the square of the current in the coil. It is the partial derivative of the coenergy *w*. In the simplest terms, *f = dw/dx*, where x is the air gap in the
solenoid.

*w = Li<sup>2</sup>/2*, so *f = dw/dx = i<sup>2</sup>/2 × dL(x)/dx*
Inductance increases as the gap is closed, so the closure force increases with smaller gap.